# Iam getting an error java.io.FileNotFoundException"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, build-automation

Iam sharing my github url

```
https://github.com/jino555/Keyword_framework/tree/master/src/config
```

Please have a look

Full Error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (utility.Log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Tools QA Projects\trunk\Hybrid KeyWord Driven\src\config\OR.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at executionEngine.DriverScript.main(DriverScript.java:39)
```

Comment: Please display your code. A link does not remplace a correct research. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you made sure this file really exists?

Comment: @S.P.H.I.N.X I was trying to set a keyword driven framework,      https://github.com/jino555/Hybrid_framework/blob/master/src/main/java/executionengine/Driverscript.java

Comment: @AutomatedOwl   yes, https://github.com/jino555/Hybrid_framework/tree/master/src/main/java/config  The file is OR.txt

Comment: check your local folder structure once

Comment: I can't help you, my office firewall don't let us access github (prevent export of code and data), so I can't see your problem. Provide a [mcve] please !

Comment: Possible problems : path incorrect, file doesn't exist, access restricted for the user. Confirm everything first, we can't confirm anythign from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
D:\Tools QA Projects\trunk\Hybrid KeyWord Driven\src\config\OR.txt
```

with:

```
D:\Tools\QA Projects\trunk\Hybrid KeyWord Driven\src\main\java\config\OR.txt
```

I believe `Tools` and `QA Projects` are diffrenet folders. Also as your gitHub repository shows the preject structure looks like:

```
...\src\main\java\config\OR.txt
```

and not like

```
...\src\config\OR.txt
```

So the problem is with the path to the file you providing. We cannot find the right path for you, because we don't know where is your project stored locally.

Comment: Soory, this is the github url "https://github.com/jino555/Keyword_framework/tree/master/src/config"

Comment: and now iam not getting any msg in console , console is blank